# Deleting a handle previously created

Tags: matlab, user-interface, handle

I am trying to delete a handle `handles.roi1` that I created.

I already tried to use the function `delete`:

```
delete(handles.roi1)
```

but it gave me this error:

```
Argument must contain a string.
```

My purpose is to delete a handle like I have never created it.

Do you have any suggestion or tips how can I do it?

---

Maybe I didn't express correctly...

I am doing a GUI, where I define in one button `handles.roi1`, but then I want to delete it on another button. This because, on that button I do:

```
try a=handles.roi1;
catch
    b=11;
```

And I want that it goes to the `catch`. I tried to do the `handles = rmfield(handles, 'roi1');` but it didn't work.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "delete a handle like I never created it"?
Can you please provide more details on your problem? how exactly do you create `handles.roi1`?

Comment: Is it possible that you overloaded `delete` function? can you please type `which delete` in your matlab's prompt and see where it points?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** Rewrote the answer to match the info added by OP.

If `handles.roi1` is created with `imread`:

```
handles.roi1 = imread('test.jpg');
```

or, storing the content first in the variable `a` and then making a copy of `a` into `handles.roi1` (in this case you have 2 copies of the same data):

```
a = imread('test.jpg');
handles.roi1 = a;
```

then there are **no** open file handles. Further, `a` and `handles.roi1` are **equal**, and they are **not** file handles, but each of them contains the color or grayscale image of the graphics file `test.jpg` (in this example case).

In MATLAB usually you get the file handle with `fopen`, but there are several file I/O commands that do **not** use file handles, for example `imread`, `xlsread` and `fastaread` do not use file handles.

In this case what you want (I assume) is to get rid of the field `roi1` of the struct `handles` (`handles.roi1` in MATLAB syntax), so you can use `rmfield` this way:

```
handles = rmfield(handles, 'roi1');
```

Which stores a new copy of `handles` without the field `roi1` back to the same struct called `handles`.

Note that this has nothing to do with file handles or with graphics object handles. It's just a struct called `handles` that you or someone has names confusingly with a name `handles`, despite the fact `imread` doesn't return any file handles (nor graphics object handles) at all! I'd rather name it `imageData` instead of `handles`, because that's what it really contains.

On the other hand, if `handles.roi1` really was a file handle created with `fopen` like this:

```
handles.roi1 = fopen('test.jpg');
```

In this case you would have a real open file handle in MATLAB, and you should first close the file with `fclose` like this:

```
fclose(handles.roi1);
```

Or alternatively, if you want to close all your open files opened with `fopen`:

```
fclose('all');
```

Then, when after `fclose` you would like to get rid of the field `roi1` of the struct `handles` (`handles.roi1` in MATLAB syntax), you could use `rmfield` this way (same as in the case of `imread`):

```
handles = rmfield(handles, 'roi1');
```

Which stores a new copy of `handles` without the field `roi1` back to the same struct called `handles`.

Comment: handles.roi1 is a matrix of a image, like a=imread('friends.jpg') and I done handles.roi1=a. But, then I want to delete the handles.roi1. How can I do it?

Comment: Could you please edit your question to expand and clarify it? The code with which you define the buttons would be useful to be able to respond your question.

Comment: try
    roi1=handles.roi1;
        h = imrect;
        roi2 = createMask(h);
        roi=roi1+roi2
        handles.roi1=roi

catch
        h = imellipse;
        roi1 = createMask(h);

The problem is hard to explain. My problem is that I want to delete the handles.roi1 to force the code to goes to the catch again.

Comment: Then you can use `handles = rmfield(handles, 'roi1');`.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to delete part of the handle, you can do as mentioned above:

```
rmfield(handles, 'roi1');
```

If you want to delete the entire handle, you can do:

```
clear handles
```

Comment: `rmfield(handles, 'roi1');` does not change anything, because `rmfield` is not an operator, it's a function (at least in R2012a), and it's not destructive. `rmfield(handles, 'roi1');` only returns the struct `handles` without the field `roi1`. If you want to clear the field `roi1`, then you need to store the output of `rmfield` back to `handles` (or somewhere else).